# How to make SVG images be displayed in a mobile device?

Tags: qt, svg, stylesheet, embedding

I am building a QT application which I customize through QT stylesheets. The images I use for the controls are SVG images which are rendered properly when ran in Linux. But when I load the QT application into a mobile device, the SVG images don't seem to appear.

Does anyone know what's going on? What should I do to make the SVG images work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the log file in your emulator and find out what is the error occurred:

svg while implementing on mobile device may fail because of the following scenarios.
1.Memory footpring issue because of different OS;mobile OS is relatively small in size.
2.Device type on which it runs.
3.Framework that is used for implementing SVG applications.The framework availability
4.Sometime image encoding can also be an issue.

So need to get a framework that support all these characters on mobile device.
Currently there are few open source and commercail frameworks available.You will get more from this link
http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/s2dvg/index.html